# How to mock an async action creator in redux with jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs

I'm trying to write a unit test for a redux async action creator using jest.

asyncActions.js:

```
const startSignInRequest = () => ({
  type: START_SIGNIN_REQUEST
});

// action creator to dispatch the success of sign In
export const signInSucceded = user => ({
  type: SIGNIN_USER_SUCCEEDED,
  user
});

// action creator to dispatch the failure of the signIn request
export const signInFailed = error => ({
  type: SIGNIN_USER_FAILED,
  error
});

const signInUser = user => dispatch => {
dispatch(startSignInRequest);
  return signInApi(user).then(
    response => {
      const { username, token } = response.data;
      dispatch(signInSucceded(username));
      localStorage.setItem("token", token);
      history.push("/homepage");
    },
    error => {
      let errorMessage = "Internal Server Error";
      if (error.response) {
        errorMessage = error.response.data;
      }
      dispatch(signInFailed(errorMessage));
      dispatch(errorAlert(errorMessage));
    }
  );
};
```

signInApi.js:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { url } from "../../env/config";

const signInApi = async user => {
  const fetchedUser = await axios.post(`${url}/signIn`, {
    email: user.email,
    password: user.password
  });
  return fetchedUser;
};
```

In the [Writing tests](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests) of redux's official documentation, they use `fetch-mock` library. However, I think that this library call the real Api.
I tried to mock the axios api using `jest mocks`.

/__mocks/signInApi.js:

```
const users = [
{
    login: 'user 1',
    password: 'password'
}
];

  export default function signInApi(user) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const userFound = users.find(u => u.login === user.login);
      process.nextTick(() =>
        userFound
          ? resolve(userFound)
          // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-promise-reject-errors
          : reject({
              error: 'Invalid user credentials',
            }),
      );
    });
  }
```

__tests/asyncActions.js:

```
jest.mock('../axiosApis/signInApi');
import * as actions from '../actions/asyncActions';

describe('Async action creators', async () => {
it('Should create SIGN_IN_USER_SUCCEEDED when signIn user has been done', () => {
    const user = {
                    login: 'user 1',
                    password: 'password'
                }
    await expect(actions.signInUser(user)).resolves.toEqual({
        user
    })
})
});
```

The test failed and I got:

```
expect(received).resolves.toEqual()

Matcher error: received value must be a promise

Received has type:  function
Received has value: [Function anonymous]
```

How can I mock this async action creator only with jest?

Comment: .You have to call the toEqual differently. You're using a Promise and you should use .resolves for example https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async#resolves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to update your mock to resolve to an object like this:

```
export default function signInApi(user) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const userFound = users.find(u => u.login === user.login);
    process.nextTick(() =>
      userFound
        ? resolve({  // <= resolve to an object
          data: {
            username: 'the username',
            token: 'the token'
          }
        })
        // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-promise-reject-errors
        : reject({
          error: 'Invalid user credentials',
        }),
    );
  });
}
```

...then what you are really testing is that `actions.signInUser` returns a *function* which can be called with a `user`...

...which then returns another *function* which can be called with a `dispatch` which dispatches the proper actions:

```
jest.mock('./signInApi');
import * as actions from './asyncActions';

describe('Async action creators', () => {
  it('Should create SIGN_IN_USER_SUCCEEDED when signIn user has been done', async () => {
    const user = {
      login: 'user 1',
      password: 'password'
    };
    const dispatch = jest.fn();
    await actions.signInUser(user)(dispatch);  // <= call the function on a user, then call the resulting function on a dispatch
    expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);  // Success!
    expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, { type: START_SIGNIN_REQUEST });  // Success!
    expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(2, { type: SIGNIN_USER_SUCCEEDED, user: 'the username' });  // Success!
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I have to edit my answer as the first one pointed to a wrong direction.

So from my understanding you want to mock the Action + Return value. In your case I would just immediately return the result of your mock function. As you're not mocking `axios.post` you don't need to wrap everything inside a promise and return that. You're not mocking only the HTTP call but the whole action.

```
const users = [
{
    login: 'user 1',
    password: 'password'
}
];

  export default function signInApi(user) {
    const userFound = users.find(u => u.login === user.login);
    return (userFound ? userFound : {
      error: 'Invalid user'
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my code but I always got an error: ```expect(received).resolves.toEqual()

    Matcher error: received value must be a promise

    Received has type:  function
    Received has value: [Function anonymous]````

Comment: Drop that, I think I read your code wrong. You're calling an action function directly.

Comment: @ModusTollens my question is 'How to mock an async action creator in redux with jest' and I know that I didn't write code as described in the official doc and as Fer To answer. However, even with, these modifications, the question is still valid and the answer does not solve the problem

Comment: So I think your mock is just wrong. You're creating a function which inside calls a promise and waits for it. But your mock function just returns a Promise, which means it is a different typ you return

Comment: The issue is that you don't need to return this Promise. You can just immediately return the data or error. Your mock function has no need to return a promise as you're mocking the whole Action creator not just axios http call.

Comment: In my case, the signInApi contains the axios api wich is asynchronous and I want to mock it in order to get a mocked response then I return a result according to the mocked axios api.

Comment: The question for me right now is, why do you want to test? Testing this action makes not much sense. mocking the whole process of a fake async call is not giving any value. You either want to check if your action does what it should do based on Ajax success / error -> then mock axios.post. If you want to test something else related to this action (e.g. a component, a user event), than test that functionality. Your Mock of a async action gives no added trust in your code base. Right now you write a mock function and test that the mock logic works.